# "document.getElementById(div).style.display = none" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide three divs when I click a button, but my js isn't working.

```
    function display() {
    document.getElementById("Contentable").style.display = none;
    document.getElementById("savebtn").style.display = none;
    document.getElementById("stylebar").style.display = none;
    }
```

When I click the button there is an uncaught reference error that says "none" is not defined.

Comment: It's supposed to be `.display = "none";`, right now all you have is syntax errors.

Comment: correct, the var none is not defined

Comment: Wow, didn't notice that. Huge brainfart on my part I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The none should be in `" "` and you can use JQuery for this as well.

```
function display() {
    $("#Contentable").hide();
    $("#savebtn").hide();
    $("#stylebar").hide();
   }
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to pass "none" as a string.

```
function display() {
    document.getElementById("Contentable").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("savebtn").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("stylebar").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Otherwise, it is interpreted as a variable name which is not defined in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`none` must be in quote, otherwise it will be consider as a variable

`element.style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 2):

You have to write `none` in double or single inverted commas `"none"`, like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to make an object disappear but have it still take up space on the HTML page, you can use the following code below:

```
document.getElementById("Contentable").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("savebtn").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("stylebar").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Otherwise, to answer your question, copy-paste the code below:

```
document.getElementById("Contentable").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("savebtn").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("stylebar").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari renders things differently and uses a UI overlay for dropdowns. You can't just hide them, but you can refresh the options match from array each time. Here I use jQuery to clear a select options each time and create new options:

```js
myFunction();

function myFunction() {

  //alert("dins");

    var select = document.getElementById("selectArticles");
  var options = ["NouCreus", "Pic de l'Àliga", "Puigmal", "Finestrelles", "NouFonts", "Núria Estació"];
  
    var i, L = select.options.length - 1;
  for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
     select.remove(i);
  }

    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("inputPatro");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  
  var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = "Vall de Núria";
      el.value = "-1";
      select.appendChild(el);

  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    if (opt.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputPatro" onchange="myFunction()" placeholder="Filtre per nom.." title="Escriu un patró per filtrar les opcionw del desplegable">
<select id="selectArticles">
</select>
```